# How do I take a picture with my built-in web-cam?

Tags: windows-7, webcam

> **Possible duplicate:** [How can I take a picture with my webcam in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/188632/how-can-i-take-a-picture-with-my-webcam-in-windows-7)

I've never used a web-cam before.  I'm guessing that there is a some pre-installed program that allows me to take a picture or a small video.

I have a HP ProBook running Windows 7.

**Edit:** I no longer possess this computer, as it was my work laptop from my previous job. I appreciate the help of recent answerers, but I won't be upvoting or accepting answers, since I cannot verify them.