# How can I take a picture with my webcam in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I know it existed as sort of a folder in Windows Explorer in at least Windows XP, but I just can't seem to find it in Windows 7...

How can I take a picture with my webcam in Windows 7 without using any 3rd party tools?

Comment: It's not included per-se, but if you use Windows Live Messenger you can go to webcam preview mode and take a screenshot of yourself.

Comment: @JohnT Messenger was decommissioned a year ago (but is still available in mainland China). I suggest upgrading to Windows 8 and using the built-in Camera app :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view my webcam in vista?](http://superuser.com/questions/65367/how-can-i-view-my-webcam-in-vista)

Comment: @EladKarako That sounds very Lenovo/IBM specific...

Comment: **For Lenovo/IBM users:** Use `"C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Communications Utility\CommMain.exe"`, or run `"C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Communications Utility\CommOSD.exe"` and press `[FN]+[F6]`, **both are similar**, using the built-in driver/program of Lenovo/IBM so it is the best solution, and you can also switch resolutions and check different camera settings while you choose your best settings. **Just click `"Take Snapshot"`**.

Comment: Not enough rep to post answer, but this one worked great for me. Fast, free, no hassle: https://webcamtoy.com

Answer (score 39):

Answer I wrote from another [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/181983/windows-7-webcam-recording-software).

Technically it isn't built in, but it is by Microsoft - so hope that doesn't count as third party in your books.

---

I find the best and quickest program to be [Microsoft AMcap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373424(VS.85).aspx).

It works via native DirectX functions and is very lightweight.

It is a free utility available through the [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=3021d52b-514e-41d3-ad02-438a3ba730ba) - and here is a direct link to [Amcap.exe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1en6vcuflhudp9/amcap.exe?dl=0).

Comment: I just downloaded the DirectX SDK (all 571MB) and installed it to Win 7 - unfortunately AMcap doesn't seem to be included any more.

Comment: Amcap is included in some webcam drivers, for example ZS0211. Google it and you'll find some downloads. For example file with that name works for me: `ZS0211_ov7648&PO2030_Setup` (exe or zip)

Comment: And AMcap.exe doesn't work alone either.....

Comment: The Microsoft version of AmCap is old abandonware (actually just a DX sample), but it seems to have been extended and maintained (at least up to 2008) by Noël Danjou, and can be downloaded e.g. here: https://en.softonic.com/download/amcap/windows/post-download?sl=1#
(The Dropbox link in the answer is 404, BTW.)

Comment: The direct link to Amcap.exe is no longer working. Can someone post a working link. Thank you.

Comment: @user674669 - Thanks, I organised my Dropbox a while ago and didn't realise it was still linked to - I've updated the link now and will try to find a more permanent link later.

Answer (score 15):

You can do that easily with an free online flash app:
http://blog.chrometaphore.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/WebcamSnapshot.swf

(it's an example but you can found a lot)

---

Edit:

https://amw.github.io/jpeg_camera/demo/

An other example of an online photobooth (using HTML5, with Flash fallback), which require no additional software

Answer (score 14):

The most straightforward way it to install Picasa ..: http://picasa.google.com/

.. click on icon for "Capture photos and videos from a webcam or other video device" ..:

[image: Take webcam picture]

.. and then take picture or record video:

[image]

Comment: While technically Picasa is a third-party tool, this answer was helpful for me since I already had it installed.

Comment: Picasa seems retired. Can't find the same feature in Google Photos.

Comment: I downloaded Picasa from https://sourceforge.net/projects/googlepicasa . I was able to take a capture a photo on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 5):

For Lenovo users, there's the Web Conferencing tool that comes with your ThinkPad that allows you to save camera snapshots. I know it's not an answer to the original question, but I arrived here via a Google search for a quick way to take a snapshot with my built in webcam so I guess more people will.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7, start Menu -> Run, type "webcam" or "camera" and you should see camera related software that came with your PC. Click on the software and that will allow you to take a pic.

Comment: Sounds good, I'd try it out if I still possessed that computer -- work laptop from previous job.

Comment: Sounds good for Windows 10, there's a camera application there.

Comment: win 7 logitech webcam, says nothing

Comment: Best answer for W10.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Picanom](http://www2.picanom.com/) -- its an online service (I don't trust such stuff much).
Your HP ProBook must have also come with its own **Webcam Software**.
<sup>Check [this for example](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4021356&prodNameId=4021357&swEnvOID=2097&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ob-84395-1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I use CommandCam: http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/commandcam/

To convert to JPEG, I use this: http://code.google.com/p/jpeg-compressor/

Comment: There are only two sentences in that question and the second one is "How can I take a picture with my webcam in Windows 7 **without using any 3rd party tools**?".

Comment: Other people searching for information on taking pictures with webcams will find this question, and my answer will be useful to them.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing I had already installed on my computer was VLC. This seems to work just fine: `Media` menu, `Open capture device...`, select the device name and click `Play` button.