# Viewing webcam in Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I take a picture with my webcam in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/188632/how-can-i-take-a-picture-with-my-webcam-in-windows-7)

I'm looking for a way to view my laptop's integrated webcam. Is there a Windows 7 equivalent to the webcam device that would show up under My Computer on Windows XP?

I can see the video in Gmail Chat, so I know the device and drivers are working correctly. I just want a way to quickly preview the webcam output without any third-party software.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/188632/how-can-i-take-a-picture-with-my-webcam-in-windows-7

Comment: @Wil - Thanks, that answers my question.