# See yourself on a webcam

Tags: windows-7, windows, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I take a picture with my webcam in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/188632/how-can-i-take-a-picture-with-my-webcam-in-windows-7)

If you have a webcam properly installed, what program (preferably built-in, Windows 7) can you use to see yourself in a window in real-time mode?

Comment: It's a little bit overkill but you could use [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/home).

Answer (score 2):

This was solved in another question through the use of AMCap.
[How can I take a picture with my webcam in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/188632/89671)