# How can I receive images from a webcam?

Tags: drivers, webcam

I was given a spare webcam, but all I've gotten right so far is to load a driver and plug it in. It is an [Isonic IS-W001B](http://www.isonic.co.za/webcams.htm#). I assume I need some software to operate it, but that web site offers nothing of the sort.

I once did something that was supposed to activate the external webcam, but it instead used my notebook's built it one, but I can't remember what procedure I followed.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is install the driver and plug it in, as you have mentioned.  No extra software needed.  Whatever software you want to use with your Webcam (such as Skype) will use it directly.

If you need to switch to that camera vs. the one built into your laptop, you would configure this in the software you are trying to use.

Comment: I'm not trying to use any software. I'm looking for software to receive images from the webcam, not use it for Skype or something.

Comment: @ProfKaos http://superuser.com/q/188632/48624